# sudo apt-get installation doesn't work

Tags: pi-2, apt

Whenever I try to use `sudo apt-get install`, or `sudo apt-get update`, for that matter, I will result in an error like this:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/raspberrypi.collabora.com_dists_wheezy_rpi_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

It used to work fine, but not anymore. sudo apt-get upgrade doesn't work either.
I have an ethernet connection.

Answer (score 1):

First you should remove the merge lists:

`sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Then try run:

`sudo apt-get clean`

Then try again.